# Windows 10 having major issues after being off for a couple of months

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, desktop

My desktop has been off for a couple of months. My water cooler went out and I only just got it replaced today. During that time it was unplugged and just sitting. While it was off at some point I removed my main hard drive (had the OS on it) to plug into another computer so I could grab a few files. The hard drive then sat out in a safe place, but unplugged for a month or two (not sure if this would affect anything)

Today I finally got the cooler replaced and turned the computer on but I'm having some major issues. First, the start menu wont open at all. Also a lot of programs wont run at all unless I run them as admin and even then some don’t work. Most of my shortcuts show up as just the white page instead of the program icon. My background isn’t loading so I just have a black background. Windows updates fail to install. It seems like programs and even certain windows functions cant read or write to the drive.  Yet it works perfectly fine when I look through files in explorer. Restarting doesn't solve anything. I don’t think it's any programs or a virus causing this as it was perfectly fine before I shut it down for a while. The disc checker utility doesn't return any errors or bad sectors. I just ran `sfc` in `power shell` and it returned no errors.

I'm really at a loss as to what to try next. I would like to avoid reformatting and reinstalling windows and save it as a last resort only. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try to fix this?

Edit: So I just booted into safe mode and things seem to be working fine. What can I do while in safe mode to help solve the problem while I'm out?

Edit 2: Start button and menu still don't work in safe mode.

Edit 3: I've been able to get programs to run, but a lot of times they can't do anything unless they are run as admin. I also found that I have to provide admin rights to access a lot of folders that typically do not require it.

Edit 4: After running a disc repair, a couple of things are working. It seems that the OS has no trouble reading/writing to the disc now. I was able to update successfully (Anniversary update), and I was hoping that would solve my problems, but no luck. I also ran the Startmenu Diagnostic tool. There were two issues, the first being The Tile database was corrupt, and this was fixed. This is the other issue:

```
Required applications are not installed correctly.    
"Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost" and "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana" applications need to be installed correctly.
```

Unfortunately, this was not fixed by the diagnostic tool.

Any other suggestions?

Edit 5: So I've been able to solve the majority of the problems.

I took ownership of the entire drive by using `takeown` and then ran `icacls` as seen in this article:

http://lallouslab.net/2009/06/14/resetting-ntfs-files-security-and-permission-in-windows-7/

After I chose the `drive > properties > security > add > Everyone > and allowed access to all settings.` I'm the only one that uses the computer, so it's not a problem.

My only remaining issue is the startmenu still won't work. I've narrowed down the problem to `WindowsShellExperience`. Turns out, the service isn't even running. I have tried countless solutions to no avail. You would think MS would have a package that you could just download and reinstall, but unfortunately no.

Comment: Is there anything on the HDD that is newer than when it was first turned off?  It's a reach, but I'm thinking the connection to the other computer may have added something so that programs don't recognise the operating system on the disk, instead they're looking for the OS on the other computer's disk.

Comment: Ryan, you can *repair* instead of reformatting/reinstalling. @mcalex if it didn't recognise the OS, then how does it boot into the OS?

Comment: My assumption was the bios and the OS recognise each other, but when trying to run the programs, the programs are looking for an OS on a different drive (similar to copying a program's directory to another machine and then trying to run the .exe file).  Like I said it was a reach.  :-)

Comment: @mcalex, No, nothing was added or changed on the hard drive itself, everything is the same.

Dave, Which repair are you referring to? I did a disc repair and that solved some things, but the majority of my issues remain.

mcalex, That sounds close to what is happening. All of my shortcuts and programs pinned to the taskbar say come up with a file not found.

Comment: When you used another computer to 'grab a few files' did you change ownership and/or permissions of anything? Especially things under your \Users directory? For example by clicking on a  dialog something like 'allow access to <xxx>'?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 when I attached it to the other computer I did have to access my user folder. It asked for admin rights to enter it, could this be the cause of my problems?

Comment: I have been doing some research. Is this something you would recommend trying:

http://lallouslab.net/2009/06/14/resetting-ntfs-files-security-and-permission-in-windows-7/

Comment: Accessing it on the other system _probably_ changed the owner. Unless your systems are in the same 'domain' (Windows domain, not DNS) the userid that appears in the UI as e.g. 'RyanL' is internally a Security Identifier something like `S-1-5-21-12345789-987654321-123456789` where the numbers are unique on each Windows system. Back on your original system those files now belong to a wrong and unknown userid. In explorer go to an affected file, rightclick, Properties, Security, Advanced (and confirm if needed), Owner and I _think_ (but can't test) it will show the problem. ...

Comment: ... If so, then either the 'Edit' button in the Owner tab or `takeown /f` with appropriate arguments in a elevated command prompt (aka 'console') should fix it; the page you link is somewhat vague but essentially correct.